# Convert String to array and validate size on Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I need to execute a SQL query, which converts a String column to a Array and then validate the size of that array

I was able to do it easily with postgresql:
e.g.

```
select
cardinality(string_to_array('a$b','$')),
cardinality(string_to_array('a$b$','$')),
cardinality(string_to_array('a$b$$$$$','$')),
```

But for some reason trying to convert String on vertica to array is not that simple, Saw this links:

https://www.vertica.com/blog/vertica-quick-tip-dynamically-split-string/
https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239031/how-to-create-an-array-in-vertica

And much more that non of them helped.

I also tried using:

```
select  REGEXP_COUNT('a$b$$$$$','$')
```

But i get an incorrect value - 1.

How can i Convert String to array on Vertica and gets his Length ?

Answer (score 1):

`$` has a special meaning in a regular expression.  It represents the end of the string.

Try escaping it:

```
select REGEXP_COUNT('a$b$$$$$', '[$]')
```

Comment: OK, Still assume It will be a different Char i would i convert String to Array on Vertica?

Comment: @BarakKedem . . . I don't see what arrays have to do with counting characters (or regular expressions) in a string.  That is a convenient method in Postgres, but there are other solutions.

Comment: I don't need to count characters I need to split a string to array by a delimiter and see how many variables in this array counting characters is nice but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a UDx scalar function (UDSF) in Java, C++, R or Python. The input would be a string and the output would be an integer. https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UDx/ScalarFunctions/ScalarFunctions.htm

This will allow you to use language specific array logic on the strings passed in. For example in python, you could include this logic:

```py
input_list = input.split("$")
filtered_input_list = list(filter(None, input_list))
list_count = len(filtered_input_list)
```

These examples are a good starting point for writing UDx's for Vertica. https://github.com/vertica/UDx-Examples

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to convert to an array - but Im able to get the length of the values
What i do is convert to Rows an use count - its not best performance wise
But with this way Im able to do also manipulation like filtering of each value between delimiter - and i dont need to use [] for characters like $

```
select (select count(1)   
        from (select StringTokenizerDelim('a$b$c','$') over ()) t)
```

**Return 3**